# PHP TesseractOCR exec command issue

Tags: php, tesseract

I have installed TesseractOCR from terminal of mac. when i run the following command from terminal it is working.

tesseract "hello.png" /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/987051047

but the same command is not working in

> exec("tesseract "hello.png" /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/987051047")

and the full code is

```
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR("hello.png");

$tmp_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') : sys_get_temp_dir();

$tesseract->setTempDir( $tmp_dir );

$test =  $tesseract->recognize();
```

I feel I have to load tesseract in php.ini or any other configuration file. but I don't know where. I am using mac, MAMP, php 5.4.10

Answer (score 1):

Ok after installation we need to change the path for bin

$path = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=$path:/usr/local/bin");

add these lines and it will work

Thanks